# Gutenberg reusable blocks - is it possible to customise an instance?

Tags: block-editor

Is it possible to have custom settings for a particular instance of a reusable block? If you change any settings/data for a reusable block it changes for all instances where that block is used. This is great for keeping blocks of content synced across a website. But it would be great to also have ability to have fields that are unique to a specific instance of a reusable block. i.e. global attributes and local attributes. Is that currently possible?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I have a feeling this isn't possible... but I really wish it would.

Comment: This sounds like something that would be better accomplished with a block pattern - a pre-defined layout of blocks which can have pre-set content & settings, and even include reusable blocks. Or maybe not. I might be able to wrap my head around it better if you can provide an example